# Capybara syntax for :with should I use '=>'? or not

Tags: capybara

As a newbie to Capybara, I'm finding some of the syntax a bit confusing as in some cases the code includes '=>' and in others it is not?

e.g.

```
fill_in 'criticality', :with => 'hello'
```

versus

```
fill_in 'criticality', with: 'hello'
```

Which is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no correct answer to this.  Ruby (since version 1.9) supports two formats for specifying Hashes (https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html)
The originally supported format was using the hash rocket format ( => ), while the second supported format (syntactic sugar/cleanup) was added in 1.9 for Hashes with symbols as keys

Originally supported format

```
{ :foo => "bar" }
```

Ruby 1.9 added format

```
{ foo: "bar" }
```

You can use whichever reads better to you in the given situation

Comment: @foxy-tester.com You're welcome - don't forget to accept the answer (the checkmark) if it has answered your question sufficiently.